# Elasticsearch Nested Object Schema design with dynamic keys

Tags: json, elasticsearch, dynamic, elastic-stack

Received below error while trying to index below JSON file in Elasticsearch 7

[JSON Link](https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonRedshift/20200511174831/us-east-1/index.json)

```
{
  "took" : 2371,
  "errors" : true,
  "items" : [
    {
      "index" : {
        "_index" : "awspricingnew",
        "_type" : "reddshift",
        "_id" : "jvOxcHIBZBHEiq-WwVYW",
        "status" : 400,
        "error" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Limit of total fields [1000] in index [awspricingnew] has been exceeded"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is with dynamic mapping encountering too many keys. Specially the product and terms listing product id as an object so the become unique entities in json object.

```
{
    "formatVersion": "v1.0",
    "disclaimer": "This pricing list is for informational purposes only. All prices are subject to the additional terms included in the pricing pages on http://aws.amazon.com. All Free Tier prices are also subject to the terms included at https://aws.amazon.com/free/",
    "offerCode": "AmazonRedshift",
    "version": "20200511174831",
    "publicationDate": "2020-05-11T17:48:31Z",
    "products": {
        "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M": {
            "sku": "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M",
            "productFamily": "Compute Instance",
            "attributes": {
                "servicecode": "AmazonRedshift",
                "location": "Africa (Cape Town)",
                "locationType": "AWS Region",
                "instanceType": "dc2.large",
                "currentGeneration": "Yes",
                "vcpu": "2",
                "memory": "15 GiB",
                "storage": "0.16TB SSD",
                "io": "0.60 GB/s",
                "usagetype": "AFS1-Node:dc2.large",
                "operation": "RunComputeNode:0001",
                "ecu": "7",
                "servicename": "Amazon Redshift",
                "usageFamily": "Dense Compute"
            }
        }
    },
    "terms": {
        "OnDemand": {
            "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M": {
                "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M.JRTCKXETXF": {
                    "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
                    "sku": "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M",
                    "effectiveDate": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "priceDimensions": {
                        "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                            "rateCode": "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
                            "description": "$0.357 per Redshift Dense Compute Large (DC2.L) Compute Node-hour (or partial hour)",
                            "beginRange": "0",
                            "endRange": "Inf",
                            "unit": "Hrs",
                            "pricePerUnit": {
                                "USD": "0.3570000000"
                            },
                            "appliesTo": []
                        }
                    },
                    "termAttributes": {}
                }
            }
        },
        "Reserved": {
            "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5": {
                "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5.6QCMYABX3D": {
                    "offerTermCode": "6QCMYABX3D",
                    "sku": "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5",
                    "effectiveDate": "2016-05-31T23:59:59Z",
                    "priceDimensions": {
                        "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5.6QCMYABX3D.2TG2D8R56U": {
                            "rateCode": "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5.6QCMYABX3D.2TG2D8R56U",
                            "description": "Upfront Fee",
                            "unit": "Quantity",
                            "pricePerUnit": {
                                "USD": "34800"
                            },
                            "appliesTo": []
                        },
                        "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5.6QCMYABX3D.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                            "rateCode": "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5.6QCMYABX3D.6YS6EN2CT7",
                            "description": "USD 0.0 per Redshift, dw2.8xlarge reserved instance applied",
                            "beginRange": "0",
                            "endRange": "Inf",
                            "unit": "Hrs",
                            "pricePerUnit": {
                                "USD": "0.0000000000"
                            },
                            "appliesTo": []
                        }
                    },
                    "termAttributes": {
                        "LeaseContractLength": "1yr",
                        "OfferingClass": "standard",
                        "PurchaseOption": "All Upfront"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I striped down one record and tried to index with dynamic mapping, which resulted in below

```
{
  "awspricingnew" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "disclaimer" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "formatVersion" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "offerCode" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "products" : {
          "properties" : {
            "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M" : {
              "properties" : {
                "attributes" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "currentGeneration" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "ecu" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "instanceType" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "io" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "location" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "locationType" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "memory" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "operation" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "servicecode" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "servicename" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "storage" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "usageFamily" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "usagetype" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "vcpu" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "productFamily" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "sku" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "publicationDate" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "terms" : {
          "properties" : {
            "OnDemand" : {
              "properties" : {
                "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "JRTCKXETXF" : {
                          "properties" : {
                            "effectiveDate" : {
                              "type" : "date"
                            },
                            "offerTermCode" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "priceDimensions" : {
                              "properties" : {
                                "KNVR5PFC54PXV76M" : {
                                  "properties" : {
                                    "JRTCKXETXF" : {
                                      "properties" : {
                                        "6YS6EN2CT7" : {
                                          "properties" : {
                                            "beginRange" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "description" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "endRange" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "pricePerUnit" : {
                                              "properties" : {
                                                "USD" : {
                                                  "type" : "text",
                                                  "fields" : {
                                                    "keyword" : {
                                                      "type" : "keyword",
                                                      "ignore_above" : 256
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "rateCode" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "unit" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "sku" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "termAttributes" : {
                              "type" : "object"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "Reserved" : {
              "properties" : {
                "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "6QCMYABX3D" : {
                          "properties" : {
                            "effectiveDate" : {
                              "type" : "date"
                            },
                            "offerTermCode" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "priceDimensions" : {
                              "properties" : {
                                "U4V6Y3USKUYCB6Q5" : {
                                  "properties" : {
                                    "6QCMYABX3D" : {
                                      "properties" : {
                                        "2TG2D8R56U" : {
                                          "properties" : {
                                            "description" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "pricePerUnit" : {
                                              "properties" : {
                                                "USD" : {
                                                  "type" : "text",
                                                  "fields" : {
                                                    "keyword" : {
                                                      "type" : "keyword",
                                                      "ignore_above" : 256
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "rateCode" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "unit" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            }
                                          }
                                        },
                                        "6YS6EN2CT7" : {
                                          "properties" : {
                                            "beginRange" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "description" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "endRange" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "pricePerUnit" : {
                                              "properties" : {
                                                "USD" : {
                                                  "type" : "text",
                                                  "fields" : {
                                                    "keyword" : {
                                                      "type" : "keyword",
                                                      "ignore_above" : 256
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "rateCode" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "unit" : {
                                              "type" : "text",
                                              "fields" : {
                                                "keyword" : {
                                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                                }
                                              }
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "sku" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "termAttributes" : {
                              "properties" : {
                                "LeaseContractLength" : {
                                  "type" : "text",
                                  "fields" : {
                                    "keyword" : {
                                      "type" : "keyword",
                                      "ignore_above" : 256
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                                "OfferingClass" : {
                                  "type" : "text",
                                  "fields" : {
                                    "keyword" : {
                                      "type" : "keyword",
                                      "ignore_above" : 256
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                                "PurchaseOption" : {
                                  "type" : "text",
                                  "fields" : {
                                    "keyword" : {
                                      "type" : "keyword",
                                      "ignore_above" : 256
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the general design principal for indexing these documents? Should I preprocess and flatten via logstash? or Is there any approach to document these json files with a precreated mapping because we don't know the keys to created under products / terms

**Overall objective is too pull the price of each product.**

Comment: U want to pull out the price per unit, am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I tried to flatten the products and terms object. But a term search yields the entire document. The overall requirement is index and build a query to pull the product and its corresponding price from the term object.

Comment: @WillBlakeCan you try to filter the json file using Logstash. You can make use of [JSON filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html). Json filter plugin takes an existing field which contains JSON and expands it into an actual data structure. May be it will help you.